# Почему не срабатывает observer в MobX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, observer

Я новичок в программировании (с Нового года). Если не считать, что 30 с лишним лет назад делал лабы на ЕС на Фортране. Так что прошу извинить, но все, что мог, просмотрел, и, вроде, все делаю правильно... 
Кто-нибудь может объяснить почему не срабатывает obsever?! Что я делаю не так?
Код для демонстрации проблемы: 
Выбранная в списке запись должна отобразиться в label. По клику запись успешно выбирается, но обновление не отображается.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';

class NotesStore {
  notes
  activeNote
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
    this.notes = [
      {id: 1, text: 'first'}, 
      {id: 2, text: 'second'},
      {id: 3, text: 'third'}
    ]
    this.activeNote = this.notes[0]
  }

  setActiveNote(note){
    this.activeNote = note
  }
};

const notesStore = new NotesStore();

const App = observer(() => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {notesStore.notes.map((note)=>
          <li 
            key={note.id}
            onClick={()=>notesStore.setActiveNote(note)}>
              {note.text}
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
      <label>{notesStore.activeNote.text}</label>
    </div>
  )
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дефолтные значения переменным `notes` и `activeNote` нужно задать до вызова `makeAutoObservable` - либо в конструкторе перед вызовом `makeAutoObservable`, либо при объявлении свойств класса.

Первый способ:

```
class NotesStore {
  notes
  activeNote
  constructor() {
    this.notes = [
      { id: 1, text: 'first' },
      { id: 2, text: 'second' },
      { id: 3, text: 'third' }
    ]
    this.activeNote = this.notes[0]
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  setActiveNote(note) {
    this.activeNote = note
  }
}
```

Второй способ:

```
class NotesStore {
  notes = [
    { id: 1, text: 'first' },
    { id: 2, text: 'second' },
    { id: 3, text: 'third' }
  ]
  activeNote = this.notes[0]
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  setActiveNote(note) {
    this.activeNote = note
  }
}
```

Comment: Надо же, работает! Спасибо!!! А в чем подвох?!

Comment: В документации у них про это не говорится, могу предположить, что в момент вызова `makeAutoObservable` собирает все, что есть в this и те параметры, у которых нет значений пропускает.

Comment: Видимо да. Спасибо!